# $.getJSON and $.ajax not workin in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Surprise, surprise... my code is working perfectly in Chrome and FF, but not in IE. The following code is doing a cross-domain JSON request. If the length of the JSON results is greater than 1, then it's suppose to display all the results with radio buttons. Otherwise, it take the single address returned and moves on to a redirect. In IE, it's always displaying the results with radio buttons, as is if it's always > 1. What am I doing wrong here? You're help is appreciated.

```
var url="http://clvplaces.appspot.com/maptools/rest/services/geocode?address=";
var address = someStreetNumber + " " + someStreetName;
var city = ", Las Vegas, NV";
var score = "&score=50";
var jsonCB = "&format=json&jsonCallback=?";

$.getJSON(url+address+city+score+jsonCB, function(results){
    if(results.response.length > 1) {
        $.each(results.response, function(i, item) {
            showAddresses(item)
        });
   }
   else {
        var busAdd = results.response[0].streetno + " " + results.response[0].streetname;
        busAdd += ", " + results.response[0].city + ", " + results.response[0].zip;
            var latLong = results.response[0].latlng;
        getJurisdiction(latLong, address);
      }
});
```

I've read that $.getJSON in IE has a tendency to cache results so to use $.ajax instead. So, I switched out the $.getJSON block for:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url+address+city+score+jsonCB,
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(results) {
    // same if - else statements here
}});
```

That change did absolutely nothing to fix the issue. Also, doing any of this server side is not an option for me... unfortunately.

EDIT/UPDATE:

The results for a single return are shown below. IE is always displaying single or multiply results from my IF statement, whereas Chrome and FF will display a single results from the ELSE statement as they should:

```
?({ 
    errormsg: '',
    response: [
        {
            latlng:'36.167352999999999,-115.148408',
            score:'50',
            streetno:'495',
            streetname:'S Main St',
            city:'Las Vegas',
            state:'NV',
            zip:'89101'
        },
    ]
})
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(results.response)` to see the difference between what's seen by IE and Firefox?

Comment: did you try clearing the cache ? You can use the IE debugger tools for this.

Comment: @raina77ow it's sowing the same JSON results.

Comment: @Psykopup Yet they're obviously are the reason why it works different. So it'd be great if you show the results: we don't even know what are these.

Comment: @raina77ow - I did the console.log(results.response) in IE and in Chrome. Chrome displayed [Object], which I was able to expand and see the result I expected. In IE however, it displayed [object Object] and I was not able to expand it to see the objects. Not sure why IE is seeing more results than what's there.

Comment: So... it appears the issue was the format of the JSON data being returned from the service I'm hitting. The developer was adding an extra comma at the end of all the responses. Thus, why IE was always seeing more than 1 response.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the url:

```
var randomNum = Math.random() * 1000  | 1;
url = url + "?randomNum=" + randomNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
type : 'GET'
```

For your Ajax Request to work in IE...

Missing the type throws an error in some versions

Comment: Adding the type did not fix the issue. I'm not getting any errors in IE. The service is actually returning the correct results in IE. The issue is that IE is returning them as multiple results, even if there's only 1 being returned. If you take a look at my code line - if(results.response.length > 1) { - IE is always displaying the results from there, not the else statement, where it should when there's only 1 results being returned.